# Excel VBA, Keep Formatting when saving as a .txt

Tags: excel, vba, csv, text, export-to-csv

I am importing a fixed width text file to Excel and then exporting it. 
I'm trying to figure out how to keep the formatting when saving.
On the import I have tried to use .NumberFormat, which forced formatting on import but on export it looses the formatting.

Text file I have imported:
[image: Text file I am importing]

my export routine:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateFixedWidthFile(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet, s() As Integer)
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim strLine As String, strCell As String

  'get a freefile
  Dim fNum As Long
  fNum = FreeFile

 'open the textfile
  Open strFile For Output As fNum
 'loop from first to last row
 'use 2 rather than 1 to ignore header row
  For i = 2 To ws.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
    'new line
    strLine = ""
    'loop through each field
    For j = 0 To UBound(s)
      'make sure we only take chars up to length of field (may want to 
      output some sort of error if it is longer than field)
      strCell = Left$(ws.Cells(i, j + 1).Value, s(j))
      'add on string of spaces with length equal to the 
      'difference in length between field length and value length
        strLine = strLine & strCell & String$(s(j) - Len(strCell), Chr$(32))
    Next j
    'write the line to the file
    Print #fNum, strLine
  Next i
 'close the file
  Close #fNum
End Sub
```

Calling it:

```
Sub CreateFile()
  Dim sPath As String
  sPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Text Files,*.txt")
  If LCase$(sPath) = "false" Then Exit Sub
  'specify the widths of our fields
  'the number of columns is the number specified in the line below +1
  Dim s(5) As Integer
 'starting at 0 specify the width of each column
  s(0) = 10
  s(1) = 2
  s(2) = 9
  s(3) = 10
  s(4) = 1
  s(5) = 20
 'write to file the data from the activesheet
  CreateFixedWidthFile sPath, ActiveSheet, s
End Sub
```

Exported Text File (see the format of 6th column is now a decimal & scientific notation):
[image: After Export]

Comment: Does it help to use .Text rather than .Value?

Comment: I'm going to test that and see

Comment: Now that I think about it, some of these are ID #'s ie. ssn, drivers license, serial, etc. So text would probably work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting the *values*, which is what you would *normally* want to use, so as to preserve the actual *values*.

If you want the string representations of these values *as it appears on the worksheet*, you need to export the *text* of the cells, not their *values*.

```
strCell = Left$(ws.Cells(i, j + 1).Text, s(j))
```

Note that this will lose numeric precision, and you're now treating numbers as text, which is going to introduce problems if these values ever need to be processed as numbers again.

Comment: the only issue now is,

Comment: sorry I hit enter and it can't edit the comment.

a space: 
30 600000
is exported as:
306 00000

Comment: Check your data, `Range.Text` gets you the *formatted cell value* as it appears on the worksheet.

Comment: Got the it working! I was using Workbooks.OpenText to import the file, now I have changed it to OpenTextFile from the scripting.filesystemobject, and the Mid function. Not really a problem, but it isn't opening the file it's own excel window, just setting the cell values in the same worksheet.